Unable to push from RStudio to GitHub - URL error 403
Hi I am new to RStudio and GitHub. I am trying to push a file from RStudio into my GitHub Repository called Testing2. It's a practical exercise that's part of the course I am doing. However, I am not able to push the file due to a URL 403 error. I am using an SSH key for version control.
Here's the message I get in the "Git Push" window on RStudio...
>>> /usr/bin/git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/main
remote: Permission to StubbyLittleMan/Testing2.git denied to StubbyLittleMan.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/StubbyLittleMan/Testing2.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
P.S. Still getting used to the jargon and lingo, please excuse my newbie language!
I expected the action to run through and push the file into my repository. Instead, I got the error as described.

403 is "unauthorized" - your credentials are correct, but that account doesn't have permission to do what you've requested. Are you sure you're permitted to push to that repo?

Also: you may have an SSH key, but with a URL starting in https you aren't using it.
